# Highcharter treemap not rendering in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard, r-highcharter

The treemap was working fine in shiny but when I converted to shinydashboard the treemap stopped working. It just show a blank block now. Any ideas how to fix this?

This is in my server.R

```
  output$TreeMap<-renderHighchart2({TM1<-hctreemap2(data = M,
                                                    group_vars = c("Status","Class","Order", "Family","Species"),
                                                    size_var = "n",
                                                    color_var = "n",
                                                    layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
                                                    levelIsConstant = T,
                                                    levels = list(
                                                      list(level = 1, dataLabels = list(enabled = T)),
                                                      list(level = 2, dataLabels = list(enabled = F)),
                                                      list(level = 3, dataLabels = list(enabled = F)),
                                                      list(level = 4, dataLabels = list(enabled = F)),
                                                      list(level = 5, dataLabels = list(enabled = F))
                                                    )) %>% 
    hc_colorAxis(minColor = brewer.pal(9, "GnBu")[6],
                 maxColor = brewer.pal(9, "YlOrRd")[8]) %>% 
    hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "<b>{point.name}</b>:<br>
               Number Measured: {point.value:,.0f}")
  })
```

This is in my ui.R

```
tabItem(tabName = "About",
            tabsetPanel(
              tabPanel("TreeMap",box(width = 12,highchartOutput2("TreeMap",height = "750px"))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had `renderHighchart2` and `highchartOutput2` also in the script.I changed them all to `renderHighchart` and `highchartOutput` now everything works again. So, for some reason you can't have both in your script, possibly, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use **`renderHighchart`** and **`highchartOutput`** instead of  `renderHighchart2` and `highchartOutput2`. Because you need heatmap pluing (and is not required by `renderHighchart2`)

Comment: When I built the example, it worked. But it still won't work in my original code.       Thank you for the help, I will have to go through my code to see what is causing the treemap not to render.